# Find a nice Linq solution to ensure defined accuracy

Tags: c#, linq

This is my Buinsess model, very narrowed down.

```
public class Container
{
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

}

public class Property
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**There is a List of Container**

1. Every Container must have the same amount of Properties
2. These Properties muss have the same values and amount.

Any Ideas?

To 1.
I used this

```
 var someAmountOfProperties = containers.All(x => x.Properties.Count() == containers.First().Properties.Count);
```

But i didn't really like it. Because of the reference to the first object.

### Update

**VALID** because amount is same and values are equal.

```
    var containers = new List<Container>
    {
        new Container
        {
            Properties = new List<Property>
            {
                new Property {Value = "2"},
                new Property {Value = "2"},
            }
        },
        new Container
        {
            Properties = new List<Property>
            {
                new Property {Value = "2"},
                new Property {Value = "2"},

            }
        },
        new Container
        {
            Properties = new List<Property>
            {
                new Property {Value = "2"},
                new Property {Value = "2"},
            }
        },
    };
```

**VALID** because amount is same and values are equal (1st and 2nds are the same).

```
  var containers = new List<Container>
            {
                new Container
                {
                    Properties = new List<Property>
                    {
                        new Property {Value = "2"},
                        new Property {Value = "5"},
                    }
                },
                new Container
                {
                    Properties = new List<Property>
                    {
                        new Property {Value = "2"},
                        new Property {Value = "5"},

                    }
                },
                new Container
                {
                    Properties = new List<Property>
                    {
                        new Property {Value = "2"},
                        new Property {Value = "5"},
                    }
                },
            };
```

Comment: What didn't you like about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Distinct` for that. First:

```
containers.Select(x => x.Properties.Count()).Distinct().Count() == 1
```

Second:

```
container.Properties.Select(x => x.Value).Distinct().Count() == 1
```

You can also check second condition on all containers at a time as well:

```
containers.All(c => c.Properties.Select(x => x.Value).Distinct().Count() == 1)
```

You can change `== 1` to `<= 1` if 0 is a valid count in your case.

**Edit.** For the second here is something that migth work:

```
containers.SelectMany(c => c.Properties.Select((x, i) => new {Value = x.Value, Index = i}))
          .GroupBy(x => x.Index)
          .All(g => g.Select(x => x.Value).Distinct().Count() == 1)
```

Comment: My bad, I wan't exact enought. The 1st, 2nd , .. value need to be the same. If the Values are the same, your example works fine. thx for that.

Comment: @user1776231, please see the edit if i understood it right. Not tested it though, so might contain some obvious typos.

Comment: Thx, I my tests worked great with that. I will take some time and think about your solution ;)

Comment: @user1776231, feel free to ask if you have any questions

Comment: There is no way to use a Linq Statement that is more readable to other devleoper how just stumble over this?